# Getting error in systemd-nspawn. Failed to create /init.scope control group: Permission denied. How do i solve this?

Tags: linux, docker, embedded-linux, linux-containers, systemd-nspawn

I am running a custom systemd-nspawn service in linux with a custom rootfs designed for it. I am able to start the container successfully and everything is working fine. But when check the status of systemd-nspawn service. I get following error.

systemd-nspawn[1896]: Failed to create /init.scope control group: Permission denied
systemd-nspawn[1896]: Failed to allocate manager object: Permission denied
systemd-nspawn[1896]: [!!!!!!] Failed to allocate manager object, freezing.
Freezing execution.

Currently pointless. Dont know how to resolve it.

Comment: Please read the text of the tags you have included on your question, for instance [tag:linux]. Your question belongs on [su] or [unix.se]. Good luck.

Comment: You tagged this with "docker"; a Docker container runs in a modified environment, with some resources shared with the host, in a way that systemd doesn't work well.  It's possible there may be a programming question here, and if there is, [edit]ing the question to include a [mcve] would be helpful.  But it also seems like this task would run better in a full virtual machine than a container.